# How to execute .pl script even if my browser trying to download it?

Tags: apache, perl, cgi, ubuntu-12.04

I've got simple script. I already test it in commandline. Everything is fine.
But my browser cannot execute it. It's always trying to download it. I've cheked all apache configuration file,but i can't find any troubles.

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available looks like this:

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/president/cgi
<Directory "/cgi-bin/ /var/www/president/cgi">
AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
AllowOverride None
Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

script is very simple

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
foreach (sort keys %ENV) {
print "<i>$_</i>: $ENV{$_}<br/>\n";
}
```

Comment: "my browser cannot execute it" shows a fundamental misunderstanding of how CGI (and server-side scripting in general) works. Your browser *is not supposed to* execute the script. Your browser is never supposed to even *see* the script. Rather, the web server (in your case, apparently Apache) should execute the script, and send the *script's output* (in this case, some plain old HTML) to the browser. Your browser only sees the HTML.

Comment: You're loading CGI.pm, but not making any use of it. That seems... sub-optimal :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should:

1. check the path to the perl
2. check the shebang, e.g. `#!/path/perl`
3. `chmod 755 /var/www/president/cgi/myscriptname.pl`, and
4. check your `error_log`! ;)

but probably the problem is

```
AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
```

this should be

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
                      ^    ^ dots here
```

You also has a wrong `<directory...` specs..

The section:

```
<Directory "/var/www/president/cgi">
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

And/or check the line such:

```
LoadModule cgi_module lib/apache2/modules/mod_cgi.so
```

Ps: Unrelated, but still a good advice, please read something about the `Plack` & `PSGI`. Could speed up your `perl-web-app` development many-many-many (really MANY) times. (you can live without such problems) :)

Comment: 1. whereis perl gave me the correct path, so you can be sure, that i did it right
2. Shebang without -w key did't change anything in the situation
3. Access right is the first thing, that i always check, and belive me, i'm super-sure about it (and yes, i check it again)
4. Thats's bad, but this dots doesn't change anything(

Comment: I mean, that i change the shebang, but it doesn't help
And i also did 'chmod +x' for my script

Comment: @user273580 Welcome to StackOverflow. The preferred way of saying 'thanks' is by accepting the most helpful answer (click on the green checkmark) to any question you ask (which also increases a bit your reputation too), and by up-voting helpful answers (if you have 15+ reputation).  Please read the [tour], and good luck with the answers.